# add checkbox to datatable while loading data from database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I can't add checkbox to my DataTable while bind data from db using ajax. How can I add a checkbox with server-side data loading?

My jQuery:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": "getBusperOrder.php",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "retrieve": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "columns": [{
                mData: 'district'
            }, {
                mData: 'deponame'
            }, {
                mData: 'busname'
            }, {
                mData: 'bonnetnumber'
            }, {
                mData: 'routename'
            }, {
                mData: 'bustype'
            }, {
                mData: 'status'
            }
        ],
    });
```

HTML:

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>District</th>
            <th>Depo Name</th>
            <th>Bus Number</th>
            <th>Bonnet Number</th>
            <th>Route Name</th>
            <th>Bus Type</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

gerBusperOrder.php

```
<?php
require('database/db.php');
$sql = "select * from bus as B left join depo as D on B.depoid=D.depoid left join district as DS on D.district=DS.id left join bustype as BS on B.bustypeid=BS.bustypeid left join route as R on B.routeid=R.routeid LEFT JOIN bustype as BT on B.bustypeid=BT.bustypeid WHERE B.busid IN(SELECT busid from bus where busid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(bus_id) from advt_book_side AS ABS INNER JOIN booking as B on ABS.booking_number=B.bookingnumber WHERE B.todate>CURDATE() GROUP BY bus_id HAVING COUNT(sides_id)=4))";
$resultset = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("database error:" . mysqli_error($db));
$data = array();
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
    $data[] = $rows;
}
$results = array(
    "sEcho" => 1,
    "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
    "aaData" => $data
);
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

I need to add a checkbox on the first column of each td with id

Comment: There's no `id` column in your table. Should that also be generated dynamically along with checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may employ [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option for that purpose:

```
"columns": [{
        mData: 'district'
        render: (_,__,rowData) => `<input type="checkbox" value="${rowData.busid}">${rowData.busid}</input>`
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: But i need to set value of checkbox from there, i tried both  {render: mData => '<input type="checkbox" value="+id"></input>'},    and {render: mData => '<input type="checkbox"></input>'+id}.

Comment: No. I got another values like,{ mData: 'district' } ,
                   { mData: 'deponame' },   . I need to assign  { mData: 'busid' } to checkbox

Comment: @Linu: If you need to put the value of another property of source data object into the cell contents, you may refer to entire row data, like in the example I've given above

Answer (score 1):

Please find this answer. You can populate checkbox from the server-side itself

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "getBusperOrder.php",
            "type": "POST"
        }
```

In the HTML you need to add

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>District</th>
        <th>Depo Name</th>
        <th>Bus Number</th>
        <th>Bonnet Number</th>
        <th>Route Name</th>
        <th>Bus Type</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Changes in PHP

```
<?php
require('database/db.php');
$sql = "select * from bus as B left join depo as D on B.depoid=D.depoid left join district as DS on D.district=DS.id left join bustype as BS on B.bustypeid=BS.bustypeid left join route as R on B.routeid=R.routeid LEFT JOIN bustype as BT on B.bustypeid=BT.bustypeid WHERE B.busid IN(SELECT busid from bus where busid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(bus_id) from advt_book_side AS ABS INNER JOIN booking as B on ABS.booking_number=B.bookingnumber WHERE B.todate>CURDATE() GROUP BY bus_id HAVING COUNT(sides_id)=4))";
$resultset = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("database error:" . mysqli_error($db));
$data = array();
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = '<div class="table-checkbox table-checkbox-data"><input type="checkbox" value="'. $rows['id'] .'"></div>';
   //insert other columns in $row array
    $data[] = $rows;
}
$output = array(
            "recordsTotal" => count($data),,
            "recordsFiltered" => count($data),,
            "data" => $data,
        );

    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: But, how can I display this checkbox on datatable?

Comment: Datatable will take care of that as per the number of columns. Glad that other solution worked for you.